# The most Pythonic way to convert source data from a Numpy array to a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy

I am reading in an Excel file and creating a Pandas data frame, as follows:

```
source_data = pd.read_excel('source_data.xlsx')
```

The data looks similar to the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Manufacturer':['<null', 'Mercedes', 'BMW', 'Audi', 'Audi', 'Audi', 'Audi', 'Audi', 'Mercedes', 'BMW'],
                          'Color':['Purple', '<null>', '<null>', 'Blue', 'Green', 'Green', 'Black', 'White', 'Gold', 'Tan']})
```

I then use the following to get the unique values of Color:

```
colors = df[df.Color.notna() & df.Manufacturer.eq('Audi')]['Color'].unique().tolist()
```

When I call:

```
type(colors)
```

I see that Python is converting this to a numpy array:

```
numpy.ndarray
```

I really need `colors` to be a `list` (so that I can pass it off to the x-axis of a Plotly chart), which is easy enough to do with the following:

```
colors = df[df.Color.notna() & df.Manufacturer.eq('Audi')]['Color'].unique().tolist()
```

My questions are:

1) Why is this being converted to a Numpy array in the first place? (I don't call Numpy anywhere)

2) Is there a Pythonic way to bring in the data and have it converted to a list without pre-processing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Pandas uses numpy under the hood, that is your first answer. Just cast it into a list. The so-called Pythonic way is not fast, vectorization of numpy is the real speed.

Comment: Plotly should accept numpy arrays as well.

Comment: Um... Did you use `.values` instead of `.tolist()`?? In any case, you can just use the array for plotly. Almost anything that accepts a list will accept an array as well

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga -- are you suggesting:  `colors = df[df.Color.notna() & df.Manufacturer.eq('Audi')]['Color'].unique().values()`?  If yes, that results in an error:  `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'values'`

Comment: No, I'm asking what you actually used, you put the same code for both things

Comment: I used _.tolist(), which works fine.  When I use _.values(), I get an error.